# min() arg empty sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning object oriented concepts in python. Below, I have created a class and a method in it. I am trying to find the minimum of a list by directly calling the `min()` function and also by calling the class method
`findMin()`.

The below code gives me an error:

> min() arg is an empty sequence

Please tell me what I am missing here.

```
class Solution:
    nums = list()
    def findMin(self, nums):
        self.nums.sort()
        out = min(self.nums)
        return out

x = [4,5,6,7,0,1,2]
y = Solution()

print min(x)
print y.findMin(x) 
print len(x)
print type(y)
print dir(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `nums` with `self.nums`.

When you write:

```
    nums=list()
```

You are setting a variable on the class.

When you write:

```
    def findMin(self, nums):
```

You are receiving the parameter in a local variable, `nums`.

When you then write `self.nums` on the next two lines, you're referencing the instance's `nums` variable, which was initialized to the value of the class's `nums` variable, which was the empty list.

As such, you are essentially sorting an empty list and then trying to find its minimum. This isn't going to work, since there's no value in an empty list to find the minimum of.

Hence, the error that you see:

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

To solve this, use `nums` rather than `self.nums`, because then you'll be referencing the parameter rather than the instance field.